# How to optimize React Photo Gallery to load large images

Tags: reactjs

Can someone help me with a problem I have?

I am new with React.js and I'm still learning.

I'm doing a project for a photography website and I have a problem.

The problem is that the photos have a resolution of height '2679 pixels' and width 4018 pixels'. I used React Photo Gallery, so they get more organized.

Now, I have a problem when opening the images, as it is too slow to open them. Should I be compressing the images?

Could someone help me with this problem or advise on any solution that will handle these photos?

Please feel free also to advise regarding a different aproach on how to solve this.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Try to use some image compressor may be it will help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'too slow to open'? That resolution is not that high so the resolution isn't the problem.

Comment: If the size of image files is too high, you may need to compress images before uploading.